# Can't login with username: admin, password: nimda in smartedit - HYBRIS?

Tags: content-management-system, sap-commerce-cloud

Why I can't login in smartedit with username:admin , password: nimda. When I go in smartedit and try to login with this user I receive below error message :

[image] **"
Name for argument type [java.lang.String] not available, and parameter name information not found in class file either. "**

From where can be the problem? I have all extensions which are needed to use smartedit. For some reason can't found user **admin -> nimda**

When I login in network tab when inspect the page has this 400 error for **admin** and **contentcatalogs**

[image]

The Hybris version is 1811v.

Comment: Have you executed an update of smartEdit extensions from hac ?

Comment: You should also probably check "create essential data"

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your answer. I executed an update and initialize but the problem is still the same

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the following questions will be helpful to analyze the problem:

1. Which version of Hybris are you using?
2. Did the build pass correctly?
3. Is it a fresh installation using some recipe? If yes, there might have occurred a problem while extracting the distribution zip and therefore it is recommended that you use a utility like 7-zip to extract it and then try again.

If it is occurring with an existing installation, please execute `npminstall` and `ant clean all updatesystem` before you try again.

If it still doesn't work, you may need to debug it using your IDE and find out the root cause.

Comment: Hi @Arvind. I already did . Uploaded more images in my question above.

Comment: The problem is there locally works fine , but on the server system has this error.

Answer (score 0):

In the second image you provided I noticed that the call to contentcatalogs fails. I checked on my machine and it seems that "**cmssmarteditwebservices**" extension is needed in order for that call to work.

PLease check in localextensions.xml ( or **hac-> Platform-Extensions**) that the following extensions are present:

```
<extension name='smarteditaddon' />
<extension name='cmssmartedit' />
<extension name='cmssmarteditwebservices' />
<extension name='cmswebservices' />
<extension name='permissionswebservices' />
<extension name='previewwebservices' />
<extension name='smarteditwebservices' />
<extension name='cmsbackoffice' />
```